# T420, Ubuntu on SSD, Windows on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I bought a Lenovo T420 with preinstalled Windows 7.

I removed the HDD and installed Ubuntu on an SSD.

Now I want to buy ultrabay (another HDD slot instead of DVD) and choose which OS to load after turning on the notebook.

Is the only thing I have to do to turn off fastboot in Windows?

Any changes needed in Ubuntu or BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off fast boot and hibernation. In some cases windows doesn't shutdown properly and goes to hibernation which may be annoying.

Also you may have to set up grub to be able to choose which OS to launch if you don't want to select which OS by using the bios and boot drive order

EDIT: It is also worth noting that Ubuntu en UEFI are not good friends. Better use legacy mode in  the bios